# Return values where JOIN connection doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, groups and agencygroupjoins:

```
groups                      agencygroupjoins
--------------------        --------------------
groupID                     joinID
groupName                   agencyID
                            groupID
```

How can I get all of the groupID, groupName records (from groups) where the groupID isn't found in agencygroupjoins?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: ended up doing: SELECT g.groupID, g.groupName FROM  groups g LEFT OUTER JOIN agencygroupjoins agj ON g.groupID = agj.groupID WHERE agj.joinID IS null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [outer join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```
SELECT groups.*
FROM   groups LEFT JOIN agencygroupjoins USING (groupID)
WHERE  agencygroupjoins.groupID IS NULL
```

Comment: Your "outer join" suggestion was correct, but your query was not.

Comment: @Brds: What was wrong with it?

Comment: Came back with no results.